# related model fields not showing

Tags: python, html, django

I am having a trouble understanding what is wrong inside my code. Please can anybody tell me why the fields in `locations = Location.objects.filter(user=add_profile.user)` are not displayed in my html page.

**models.py**

```
class Location(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    my_location = models.CharField(max_length=120, choices=LOCATION_CHOICES)
    update_date = models.DateField(auto_now=True, null=True)
    date = models.DateField()

def __str__(self):
    return self.my_location


class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    user_base = models.CharField(max_length=120, choices=LOCATION_CHOICES)
    user_position = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    user_phone = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=120, null=True)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=120, null=True)
    slug = models.SlugField()

def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    self.slug = slugify(self.user)
    super(UserProfile, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

def __unicode__(self):
    return self.user.username
```

**views.py**

```
@login_required
def details(request, user_slug):
    add_profile = UserProfile.objects.get(slug=user_slug)
    locations = Location.objects.filter(user=add_profile.user)
    print(locations)
    context = {'add_profile': add_profile, locations: "locations"}
    return render(request, 'details.html', context)
```

Though, the `print(locations)` is printing the requested data inside my cmd.

**html code**

```html
{% for l in locations %}
    <ul>
        <li> {{l.my_location}} </li>
    </ul>
{% endfor %}
```

My problem is that I am not having any an error to do know where to look.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of

`context = {'add_profile': add_profile, locations: "locations"}`

should be

`context = {'add_profile': add_profile, 'locations': locations}`

Instead of using `locations` as value for context, you've used it as key and as value just the string "locations".

Comment: OMG, i feel so stupid right now. I looked at that piece of code for 1 hour. :(.